# NSTimer's action method is not being called

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I have the following code to create an `NSTimer` which should update a label each time it fires:

.h file

```
@interface Game : UIViewController
{
    NSTimer *updateTimer;

    UILabel *testLabel;
    int i;
}
-(void)GameUpdate;

@end
```

.m file

```
@implementation Game

-(void)GameUpdate
{
    i++;
    NSString *textToDisplay = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Frame: %d", i];
    [testLabel setText:textToDisplay];
    NSLog(@"Game Updated");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01428 target:self selector:@selector(GameUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

//other methods (viewDidUnload, init method, etc.)

@end
```

When I run it, a label appears in the top that says "0" but does not change. It makes me believe I missed something in how the `NSTimer` is to be setup. What did I miss?

I used breakpoints and (as you can see) logging to see if the method is actually running, rather than some other error.

Comment: So is the method actually running? Are you seeing "Game Updated" more than once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your callback must have this signature:

```
-(void)GameUpdate:(NSTimer *)timer
```

This is explicitly in the docs. And the @selector() reference when you setup the timer should be `@selector(GameUpdate:)` (notice the trailing `:`).

Try that.

Answer (score 14):

I was having a similar problem, and it had a different root cause, related to the run loop.  It's worth noting that when you schedule the Timer with the code:

```
updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01428 target:self selector:@selector(GameUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The timer will get scheduled with the **current** thread's runLoop.  In your case, because you make this call within the viewDidLoad, it is the main thread, so you are are good to go.

However, if you schedule your timer with a thread other than the main thread, it will get scheduled on the runLoop for that thread, and not main.  Which is fine, but on auxiliary threads, you are responsible for creating and starting the initial run loop, so if you haven't done that - your callback will never get called.

The solution is to either start the runLoop for your auxiliary thread, or to dispatch your timer start onto the main thread.

to dispatch:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01428 target:self selector:@selector(GameUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
});
```

To start a runloop:

After creating a thread using your API of choice, call CFRunLoopGetCurrent() to allocate an initial run loop for that thread. Any future calls to CFRunLoopGetCurrent will return the same run loop.

```
CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01428 target:self selector:@selector(GameUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for tacking that answer on. I had the same problem.

Comment: Thanks man, and not a single word inside header's documentation! What a shame Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this, I want to point out that this:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Frame: %d", i];
```

Needs memory management.

Safely replace with:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Frame: %d", i];
```

for the same effect but no need for memory management.

P.S. At time of writing I cannot comment on the original post, so I've added this as an answer.

EDIT: As [adam waite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1050447/adam-waite) pointed out below, this isn't really relevant anymore with the widespread usage of ARC.

Comment: You didn't really explain 'needs memory management' there... `initWithFormat` returns a retained instance whereas `stringWithFormat` returns an autoreleased instance. Most methods describing the return value in the method name (`arrayWithArray` etc) follow this convention throughout Cocoa. Not that it's relevant with ARC any more!

Answer (score 0):

I have had a little bit different issue with *NSTimer* - scheduled method call was ignored during UITableView scrolling.
Timer had been started from main thread. Adding timer explicitly to main run loop resolved the problem.

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:playbackTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Solution found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2716605/1994889

**UPD**: `CADisplayLink` fits much better for updating UI.
According official documentation, CADisplayLink is a:

> Class representing a timer bound to the display vsync.

And can be easily implemented like:

```
  playbackTimer = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateUI)];
 [playbackTimer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

and removed like

```
if (playbackTimer) {
    [playbackTimer removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    playbackTimer = nil;
}
```