# Using NSTimer to call performSelectorOnMainThread

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nstimer, performselector

I am able to call `pushIncompleteDataToServer` in below line.

```
[sharedDataController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pushIncompleteDataToServer) 
                                       withObject:sharedDataController 
                                    waitUntilDone:NO].
```

Now i want to call it with a `NSTimer` in an interval to 5.0 sec

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
                                 target:sharedDataController 
                               selector:@selector(**pushIncompleteDataToServer**) 
                               userInfo:[ self userInfo] 
                                repeats:YES];
```

instead of `pushIncompleteDataToServer` I want to call `performSelectorOnMainThread` (what in the first statement) . How to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placing an NSTimer in a separate thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715844/placing-an-nstimer-in-a-separate-thread)

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
                                 target:sharedDataController 
                               selector:@selector(pushData) 
                               userInfo:[ self userInfo] 
                                repeats:YES];


-(void)pushData {
    [sharedDataController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pushIncompleteDataToServer) 
                                           withObject:sharedDataController 
                                        waitUntilDone:NO].

}
```

Comment: Ugly.  Better is to schedule the timer on the main run loop.

Comment: The selector is likely wrong: `@selector(pushIncompleteDataToServer)` should probably be `@selector(pushIncompleteDataToServer:)`

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I don't think so; I think the use of `performSelectorOnMainThread` is wrong as it's passing `self` to the method.

Comment: @trojanfoe I meant the selector used in method `pushData`. Apparently, the method `pushIncompleteDataToServer` has a parameter (indicated by the argument _sharedDataController_ given in parameter _withObject_ in `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`). But it could be another issue as well ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Yes, but my point is that there shouldn't be a parameter specified (it should be `nil`).  If that method wasn't being called then the OP would know about it already, so the selector is likely correct.

Comment: @trojanfoe Agreed, could be this as well ;)